# How to use a for-loop within a for-loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm kind of new to R, but I've got some experience with Java. In Java I used to code with for-loops in other for-loops, but I've noticed that this doesn't work the same way in R.

```
p <- 11
diags <- list(rep(0.30, p), rep(0.45, p), rep(0.25, p)) 
Matrix <- as.matrix(bandSparse(p, k = -c(-1:1), diag = c(diags), symm=FALSE)) 
Matrix[1,1] <- 0.70
Matrix[11,11] <- 0.75

vector <- rep(0, 11)
vector[5] <- 1
vector

for(i in 1:240){
    e <- vector %*% (Matrix %^% i)
    for(j in 2:24){
        cumulativeSum <- cumulativeSum + e[j]
    }
}
```

I want to walk through the second for-loop for every matrix-multiplication which is done in the first for-loop. I've tried several things without the result I wished for and I hope that someone can help me out with this.

Comment: Where do you initialize `cumulativeSum`? Also, R is not like Java. R-level loops are usually the least efficient way to achieve something. Instead vectorized functions, i.e. C-level loops, are preferable.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't post the initialization of cumulativeSum. In my code it's set at zero by: cumulativeSum <- 0

Comment: What is the result you wished for? What are the errors? How do you know it is incorrect? etc. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What does %^% do? edit: found out, need library(expm) for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as far as I understand, `e` is 1x11 matrix, so looping through it with index 2:24 is weird.

Secondly, since it's a single row on numbers, then `sum()` work, don't need to loop through it.

```
for(i in 1:240){
  e <- vector %*% (Matrix %^% i)
  cumulativeSum <- cumulativeSum + sum(e)
}
```